# HTML5 validation of e-mail fails

Tags: html, validation, email, input

I recently had to exemplify a list of e-mail addresses which I did by double quoting the original address and append `@example.com`.

For example

> foo@bar.baz

I converted to

> "foo@bar.baz"@example.com

To my big surprise I found that the resulting e-mail address validates as invalid in the HTML5 input=email field validation, i.e.

```
<input name='foo' type='email' required='required' />
```

Does this not make the build in HTML5 validation of e-mail addresses completely useless as it block potential valid e-mail addresses, or am I missing something here?

Comment: You can [provide a `pattern`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19605773/11683) that [suits you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27000682/11683).

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 In Built email validation provides very basic validation.
If you want to cover each and every scenario consider using a library or handle using regex.

Comment: But a "basic validation" should not mark valid input as invalid IMHO. A basic validation would be to test for "@" for example.